# When can $(document).width() and $(window).width() show different values?

Tags: jquery, html

When can the values of the two differ?

Comment: window.width will return the current width of the window inself, so for example, if its been rezied... Document.width will show the total width of the document.

Comment: You should post that as an answer Graeme.

Comment: Please post as an answer Graeme :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.width will return the current width of the window inself, so for example, if its been rezied... Document.width will show the total width of the document.

Answer (score 5):

When you have a scrollbar on the webpage.

Comment: +1 Short and to the point. Maybe add a little more detail? (When not maximized, it has slight margins on the sides too)

Answer (score 3):

Document.width will show the total width of the document.but window.width will return the current width of the window itself,if its been rezied.

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

please check this link for more details.[here](http://api.jquery.com/width/)